# What does "Handle bad layers" mean?

Tags: qgis, layers

I saved a map, and when I went to open it back up, I was prompted with a dialogue box saying Handle Bad layers.  What does this mean? The map was fine when I saved it.

Comment: You may get this error message too if you had temporary layers (e.g. from Proceesing) in your project. So you better save them to a permanent locaction before closing the project.

Answer (score 3):

It means the layers cannot be found anymore. Maybe you moved the .qgs map file (so relative links are broken) or you moved/renamed the layers, or the database connection cannot be re-established.

You should use this dialog to point to the proper layers, else they will be removed from your map (leading to lots of frustration later on)